# What are small tiny pieces of paper of different colors that people often throw into the air at a wedding or when celebrating?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

[image]

**What are small tiny pieces of paper of different colors that people often throw into the air at a wedding or when celebrating?**

Do we call these pieces "**glittery tiny paper**"?

Also, there are smaller pieces of glittery paper that women often put on their faces (see the picture below). **What do they called?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The word is **confetti**. It's a borrow from Italian.

(Note it's a plural. The singular would be *confetto*, but you aren't likely to see that. Definitely not in English.)

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confetti), have a whole Wikipedia article about them, including the etymology.

Comment: See my updated question. Also, there are smaller pieces of paper that women often put on their faces. **What do they called?**

Comment: @Tom I'm under the impression that this is what they call *glitter*. But I'm not a user, and I'm not too sure.

Comment: @Divizna - yes, it's glitter, or glitter makeup, or cosmetic glitter, etc. It is not usually made of paper, though. Usually particles of metal, plastic, and coloured minerals.